# Accidentally remove perl5 and hundreds system packages in Ubuntu, how to restore?

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently i typed in terminal

```
sudo apt remove perl5
```

and press enter.

this action removed not only perl5 from ubuntu, but many other system packages, and even kernel modules.
Here's what apt printed in terminal while removing is going on.

https://pastebin.com/AKUQUdwQ

System works, even after reboot, but I think that I removed some important packages. How to get system back without any backups? Manually install all removed packages?

OS details: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS desktop

My fear is that perl was needed by the system packages. Now i noticed that gnome-control-center and git were removed, and I manually reinstall it.

Comment: What's your evidence that you removed "important" packages? Apt should not remove anything needed by anything else than perl.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, but if you remove a package, everything that relies/depends on that package will be removed also; which is why you're asked to confirm the removal of packages. Don't say "y" to accept the changes if it looks wrong.  As we don't know what system you're using (desktop? server? release etc - packages match 20.04/focal - but it's best if we're told!) we don't know what is expected for your *unstated* system.

Comment: My fear is that perl was needed by the system packages. Now i noticed that gnome-control-center and git were removed. Added OS deatils: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS desktop

Answer (score 2):

As you discover applications that are missing (like gnome-control-center and git), simply reinstall them.

Apt will automatically handle all the dependencies (including perl)

If applications are missing and you don't notice, then perhaps you don't need them anymore anyway.

This kind of huge autoremoval usually happens under any of three circumstances:

- The user has been mucking about with `apt-mark`.
- The user DIDN'T use the normal Desktop installer. The Desktop installer protects from mass autoremovals, the netinstall/minimal image does not.
- The user changed their Desktop environment sometime in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire *dpkg* database (located at `/var/lib/dpkg`) is backed up many times over at `/var/backups`. There should be up to 7 copies of each file in the database.

However, if I were you, the **first** thing I would do is **back up EVERYTHING that you currently have** before you do anything else (just in case things somehow end up worse. You will be using powerful commands in dangerous places.)

Comment: Yes, there is backups  dpkg database in /var/backups. How to inflate it?

Comment: with  _gzip_. They are just `.gz` files...

Comment: After you switch them out, you need to run apt upgrade to get the effect. The ones with 0 are newest, then 1, etc. The best approach is probably to switch the out entire set at once (again, after backing up) so you know you have a configuration that was running at some point. I personally would go with the `.1.gz` set. Remember, each time you make a change to apt/dpkg (update included), the rotater gets rid of the oldest, so take that into account if you need a redo.